# Customize JTable like Eclipse property window

Tags: java, swing, treetable

I have to create a table like property window in eclipse. I have created the it with help of `JXTreeTable`. But the problem is I can't able to customize a specified cell as combo box like in Eclipse property window.

How to customize `JTable` like Eclipse property window?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For non trivial components like combo boxes, buttons or whatever you have to write your own `TableModel`.
Have a look at [that](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for further explanations.